# For which $n$ does $p_n(x)=\sum\limits_{{k=1,(k,n)=1}}^n o(k) x^k $ have exactly two real roots?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, roots, multiplicative-order

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed and denote by $o(k)$ the multiplicative order of $k$ modulo $n$. Define $$p_n(x)=\sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ (k,n)=1}}^n o(k) x^k ;$$here the sum is taken over $k$ that are coprime to $n$, so $o(k)$ is well-defined. Here are two simple observations:

- If $n$ is even, $p_n(x)$ is odd. Further, in this case it only has one real root.
- If $n$ is odd, aside from $n=1$ it seems that $n$ has an even number of real roots. Here is a picture of the number of roots for $1\le n \le 1000$ and $n$ odd.

[image]

I checked OEIS and it didn't return any matches. Perhaps this problem is very difficult, as I don't know how easy it is to compute $o(k)$ for arbitrary $n$. If we denote $R(n)$ as the number of real roots of $p_n(x)$ for odd $n$, here are some questions I think are worth pursuing about $R(n$):

1. Is there an estimate or asymptotic for $R(n)$? Is there an upper bound for $R(n)$?
2. When does $R(n)=2$? For $1\le n\le 1000$, this occured when $n=\{3, 5, 7, 11, 31, 89, 127, 257, 331, 635\}$; OEIS didn't recognize this sequence either.
3. As a follow-up, does $R(n)=2$ infinitely often?

Comment: Is $R(n)$ the number of roots with or without multiplicity?

Comment: I would say with multiplicity, if that helps. Empirically, I couldn't find a case with multiple roots, but go for it!

Comment: I doubt there's an asymptote for $R(n)$ seeing that it is jumping around a lot on the graph, but there may be one for $\sum_{k=1}^n R(k)$.

Comment: One issue I'm seeing with getting more data is computation time. I'm using Sagemath, so I don't think it has the fastest root-finding algorithms, but finding the roots in the $n = 600$ range, for instance, takes two to three minutes, and the time seems to increase exponentially. As a SWAG, I suspect there's no upper limit, but it'll take longer and longer to find higher numbers of roots. There's probably something special about values with $R(n)=2$ but it's hard to say from sparse data. All those values are prime except the last one.

Comment: A couple of quick things, though... all of these polynomials have a root at $x=0$, and no positive roots (via Descartes). A quick look shows that most of the polynomials have at least one root very close to $x=-1$, within $\pm 0.1$ or so. Most of the polynomials with four or more roots have one root at a relatively high (negative) value, and one root close to zero ($-0.25 < x < 0$). The two-root polynomials for $n \geq 31$ all have their second root close to $x=-1$. But no real rhyme or reason.

Comment: Also: calculating $ord_n(k)$ is computationally pretty easy--a fraction of a second to calculate all $100000$ of them for $n = 100001$. Something I learned: if $n$ is prime, then $ord_p(k)$ is a divisor of $p-1$ for all $k$, and the multiset of orders is exactly the reduced denominators of the fractions $\frac{k}{p-1}$... but not in *order*. For $n=13$, the ordered sequence is $(1,12,3,6,4,12,12,4,3,6,12,2)$, and the fractions are $\frac{1}{12}, \frac16, \frac14, \frac13, \frac{5}{12}, \frac12, \frac{7}{12}, \frac23, \frac34, \frac56, \frac{11}{12}, \frac11$.

Answer (score 3):

**Decomposition of $p_n$**

Let $n$ be odd. Then we have
$$
(n,2k)=1 \wedge 2k<n  \Leftrightarrow (n,k)=1 \wedge k<n/2. 
$$
Thus, the terms with even exponents can be written as
$$
\sum_{\ell<\frac n2} o(2\ell) x^{2\ell}.
$$
The remaining odd numbers can be written as $n-2\ell$. Thus, we can write $p_n$ as
$$
p_n(x)=\sum_{\ell<\frac n2} o(2\ell) x^{2\ell} + \sum_{\ell<\frac n2} o(-2\ell) x^{n-2\ell} \ \ \ (1)
$$
so that the first sum gives even exponents, the second sum gives odd exponents.

Obviously, there are no positive real roots. As observed in comments, $x=0$ is a real root. Aside from $x=0$, all real roots must be negative. Then $-x\leq 0$ is a real root if and only if the following holds.
$$
\sum_{\ell<\frac n2} o(2\ell) x^{2\ell} = \sum_{\ell < \frac n2} o(-2\ell) x^{n-2\ell}. \ \ \ (2)
$$

For any $k$ with $(n,k)=1$, there is a relation between $o(k)$ and $o(-k)$.
Explicitly, this is
$$
o(-k)=\begin{cases} \frac{o(k)}2 &\mbox{ if }o(k) \mbox{ is even and } \frac{o(k)}2 \mbox{ is odd}\\
o(k) &\mbox{ if } o(k) \mbox{ is even and }\frac{o(k)}2 \mbox{ is even}\\
2o(k) &\mbox{ if } o(k) \mbox{ is odd.}
\end{cases} \ \ \ (3)
$$
This shows that we only need to compute $o(k)$ when $k<\frac n2$. Then $o(-k)$ is obtained as above. This might help reducing the computing time.

**An upper bound of $R(n)$**

By Descartes' rule of signs, we have
$$
R(n)\leq \phi(n).
$$

**Zero-free intervals**

Let $\lambda(n)$ be the exponent of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ (Carmichael's function).
The LHS of (2) is $2x^{n-1} + \sum_{2\ell<n-1} o(2\ell)x^{2\ell}$, the RHS of (2) is $x+\sum_{2\ell<n-1}o(-2\ell)x^{n-2\ell}$.

First, we use $o(2\ell)\geq 0$ on LHS of (2), and $o(-2\ell)\leq \lambda(n)$ on RHS of (2). By the geometric series partial sum formula,
$$
x + \lambda(n) \frac{x^3-x^n}{1-x^2} \geq \text{RHS} .
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\text{LHS}\geq 2x^{n-1}.
$$
After some manipulation, we have $\lambda(n) x^n + 2x^{n-1} < 2x^{n+1} + x + (\lambda(n)-1) x^3$ when $x \geq \tau=\frac{\lambda(n)}4+\sqrt{1+\frac{\lambda(n)^2}{16}}$. This gives
$$
\text{LHS}\geq 2x^{n-1} > x + \lambda(n) \frac{x^3-x^n}{1-x^2} \geq \text{RHS}.
$$
Thus, there is no real root of (2) when $x\geq \tau$.

Next, we use $o(2\ell)\leq \lambda(n)$ on LHS of (2), and $o(-2\ell)\geq 0$ on RHS of (2). By the geometric series partial sum formula,
$$
\text{LHS}\leq 2x^{n-1} +\lambda(n) \frac{x^2-x^{n-1}}{1-x^2}.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\text{RHS}\geq x.
$$
After some manipulation, we have $\lambda(n) x^2  + x^3 < 2x^{n+1} + (\lambda(n)-2)x^{n-1} + x$ when $0<x\leq \mu=-\frac{\lambda(n)}2+\sqrt{1+\frac{\lambda(n)^2}4}$.
This gives
$$
\text{LHS}\leq 2x^{n-1} +\lambda(n) \frac{x^2-x^{n-1}}{1-x^2}<x\leq \text{RHS}.
$$
Thus, there is no real root of (2) when $0<x\leq \mu$.

Hence, the equation (1) does not have any real root when
$$
x\in \left(-\infty, -\left(\frac{\lambda(n)}4+\sqrt{1+\frac{\lambda(n)^2}{16}}\right)\right] \cup \left[-\left(-\frac{\lambda(n)}2+\sqrt{1+\frac{\lambda(n)^2}4}\right), 0\right).
$$
By Intermediate Value Theorem, there is at least one real root of (2) in the interval $(\mu,\tau)$. Therefore, there is at least one real root of (1) in the interval $(-\tau,-\mu)$ for any odd $n$.

**Fermat prime case**

Let $n=2^{2^m}+1$ be Fermat prime. Then by (3), we have
$$
o(-2\ell)=o(2\ell) \ \textrm{ if } 2\ell < n-1.
$$
Thus, we obtain
$$
\textrm{LHS} = 2x^{n-1} + \sum_{2\ell < n-1} o(2\ell) x^{2\ell},
$$
$$
\textrm{RHS} = x + \sum_{2\ell < n-1} o(2\ell) x^{n-2\ell}.
$$

For $x=1$, we see that
$$
\textrm{LHS}=2+\sum_{2\ell < n-1} o(2\ell),
$$
$$
\textrm{RHS} = 1 + \sum_{2\ell < n-1} o(2\ell). 
$$
This gives $\textrm{LHS} = \textrm{RHS}+1 > \textrm{RHS}$ at $x=1$.

Previously, we have seen that $\textrm{LHS}<\textrm{RHS}$ if $0<x\leq \mu$. Since $\mu<1$, we obtain that there is at least one root of (2) in the interval $(\mu, 1)$. Hence, for $n=3,5,17,257,65537$, there is a real root of (1) in the interval $(-1,-\mu)$.

Currently, we do not know whether there are infinitely many Fermat primes.

Comment: Just quick questions/thoughts: (a) The transition from (1) to (2) works because if $x$ is negative, the second term in (1) must be negative as well. Correct? (b) Sadly the computation time of the orders is immensely smaller than the root-finding time... but could those summations be expanded and some of the polynomial terms actually be removed without changing the roots? That's not something I've seen before but it'd be cool!

Comment: (a) The second term in (1) will be negative if $x<0$. (b) That might be true that root-finding is more computationally demanding. We can see that the second polynomial has $n-2\ell$ as exponents, they might not be nicely canceling out.

Comment: One thing we might expect is that if $x$ is sufficiently large in (2), then there's no more real roots as LHS gets bigger.

Comment: Ah, because large $x$ means extremely large $x^{100}$. As far as removing terms from polymonials, I realized that $(x-z)(x-\overline{z})p(x)$ must have the same real roots as $p(x)$. Not sure if the transformation is possible without knowing the complex roots, though. (Examine, for instance, $p_1(x) = x^4-3x^3-2x^2+10-12$ and $p_2(x) = x^2-x-6$. Real roots of both are $(3, -2)$, complex roots of the first are $(1+i, 1-i)$. I don't think there's an easy transform though.)

Comment: Let $\lambda(n)$ be the exponent of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ (Carmichael lambda function). Then there is no real root when $x\geq\lambda(n)$.

Comment: Comparing with the largest $o(-2\ell)$ which is $\lambda(n)$ on the RHS, and the smallest $o(2\ell)$ which is $1$ on the LHS gives the above result.

Comment: Also by the opposite way, taking smallest $o(-2\ell)$ which is $1$ on the RHS, and the largest $o(2\ell)$ which is $\lambda(n)$ on the LHS gives no real root when $x\leq 1/\lambda(n)$. For the above two comments and this one, I am considering roots $-x$ in (1), so I am using $x$ in (2).

Comment: Interesting! So the real roots then are restricted by $-1/\lambda(n) \leq x \leq -\lambda(n)$, if I understand you correctly? (Ignoring the root at $x = 0$). Checking the calculations, this holds empirically for the large (small) root; in fact for most (odd) $n$ the lowest root is $x > \frac12 \lambda(n)$. Mostly this holds for the roots closest to $0$, but not always. For instance, for $n = 33, \lambda(n) = 10$, there's a root at $x = -0.0996$. Whether this is error in the root-finding function, I couldn't readily tell you.

Comment: I made some mistakes in the comments, I updated my answer to include the most recent findings. The lower bound was changed in my answer.

Comment: My mistake was from the lower bound of $o(2\ell)$ and $o(-2\ell)$. The lower bounds are $1$ provided that $(n,\ell)=1$. So, the universal lower bounds should be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

With the admission that this isn't an answer *per se* but an interesting bit of data, this wasn't going to fit in just a comment.

I noticed that a lot of values of $n$ had a root very close to $x=-1$. Like, very, very close. I thought "Hey, what if we calculate the function's value *at* $x=-1$ and see what we get."

I got a lot of $1$s. A bunch of other numbers as well, of course, but too many $1$s. If we treat $\text{ord}_n(0)$ as something that is defined, and set it to $\text{ord}_n(0) = -1$, here's the list of values of $n < 5000$ that have a root at exactly $x = -1$:

$$n = \{3, 5, 9, 15, 17, 25, 27, 29, 33, 35, 45, 51, 65, 69, 75, 81, 85, 87, 99, 115, 125, 135, 141, 143, 145, 153, 165, 177, 185, 195, 221, 225, 243, 247, 249, 255, 257, 289, 321, 357, 365, 375, 405, 423, 425, 445, 455, 459, 477, 481, 485, 501, 535, 537, 561, 565, 575, 585, 625, 641, 675, 679, 681, 705, 729, 765, 771, 789, 825, 841, 845, 867, 915, 935, 951, 965, 1041, 1059, 1071, 1077, 1105, 1109, 1125, 1149, 1173, 1215, 1275, 1285, 1287, 1345, 1377, 1401, 1411, 1435, 1437, 1445, 1479, 1509, 1513, 1515, 1547, 1565, 1605, 1689, 1735, 1755, 1761, 1765, 1799, 1815, 1819, 1875, 1923, 1945, 1955, 1977, 2025, 2037, 2115, 2125, 2157, 2187, 2235, 2245, 2255, 2295, 2313, 2329, 2415, 2425, 2509, 2517, 2535, 2589, 2601, 2661, 2675, 2787, 2805, 2827, 2845, 2873, 2875, 2895, 2949, 3009, 3057, 3125, 3185, 3205, 3237, 3315, 3349, 3375, 3435, 3561, 3617, 3645, 3825, 3849, 3855, 3921, 3957, 3961, 3995, 4101, 4125, 4131, 4199, 4205, 4277, 4315, 4317, 4335, 4369, 4461, 4569, 4575, 4589, 4675, 4857, 4913, 4947, 4981\}$$

I have no clue how to interpret this, or whether it can be usefully interpreted. While these get sparser as you go up the number line, they keep appearing. The smallest above $100000$ is $n = 100041$; I haven't yet found one above $n = 10^6$.

Comment: Nice observations. With the usual definition $\mathrm{ord}_n(0)=0$, we never have $x=-1$ as a root when $n\ge 3$ is odd. This is because $\sum \mathrm{ord}_n(k)$ is odd for any odd $n$.

Comment: I proved that your list should contain all product of distinct Fermat primes. For such numbers, the only element of odd order in  $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\deg(p_n) = n-1$.

$p_n$ has $2d_n$ non-real roots thus $n-1-2d_n$ real roots counted with multiplicity, maybe you just didn't find the rare cases where it has some double real roots.

For $n$ even then $p_n$ is odd and it is $> 0$ on $(0,\infty)$ thus its only one real root is at $0$.

The same holds when replacing $order(k\bmod n)$ by any non-negative function such that $f(n-1)>0$.

Not convinced that we can say anything about $R(n)$, do more simulations and see if some non-random estimate pops up.

Comment: "$p_n$ has $2d_n$ non-real roots"; why is this true? I looked briefly at some papers about polynomials with non-negative coefficients, but nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry Because polynomials of real coefficients have a non-real root, then its complex conjugate is also a non-real root.